# IOException coming out of Spring RestTemplate Not picked up by custom ResponseErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using `Spring's RestTemplate` to do some API calls to a third party service.

Everything works as expected when the response comes back as a `200 SUCCESS`.

However, when the response is a `400-level error`, I'm getting an `IOException` from deep in the belly of the `RestTemplate` code.

This is frustrating, because I've actually written my own implementation of `ResponseErrorHandler`, that checks for certain non-200 errors and does something of my choosing (logging, reformatting, etc.)

On every other third party API, my implementation of `ResponseErrorHandler` works, but for this server in particular, all non-200 errors result in this `IOException`, and my custom implementation is never reached.

> Note: Curl seems to return the error normally when I try hitting this
>   third-party endpoint.

Is this a *Spring* bug? Am I doing something stupid? Ideas for how to workaround?

**Relevant code**

Stack Trace of exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://third-party.com/api/v2/some-resource": Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://third-party.com/api/v2/some-resource; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://third-party.com/api/v2/some-resource
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:607) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.myowncode.commons.client.RestClient.send(RestClient.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
```

**Usage of my custom ResponseErrorHandler**

```
this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new LoggingResponseErrorHandler());
```

**Example of my custom ResponseErrorHandler**

(this should be irrelevant, because the above happens regardless of whether I've registered this or not)

```
public class LoggingResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingResponseErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        // do my own thing
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        // do my own thing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is connected with the use of BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory. A SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest appears to let the IOException escape its executeInternal() method whereas the non-buffered version, SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest, catches and ignores it which will presumably allow you to handle the response.

```
    @Override
protected ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(HttpHeaders headers) throws IOException {
    try {
        if (this.body != null) {
            this.body.close();
        }
        else {
            SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.addHeaders(this.connection, headers);
            this.connection.connect();
            // Immediately trigger the request in a no-output scenario as well
            this.connection.getResponseCode();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // ignore
    }
    return new SimpleClientHttpResponse(this.connection);
}
```

try creating your restTemplate like this:

```
this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
```